# Motherboard for mid-level virtualization server

Tags: desktop, server, virtual-machines

*[Edit] restated question trying to emulate a different format found in [this request](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/239/) more closely.*

I'm looking to have a mid-level virtualization and media server for an extended home environment, and I am looking to spend in the neighborhood of $1,000 (+/-$100) for the core components (MOBO, CPU, and Memory), as I have a case, a single power supply, and several HDD/SSD options on hand already. It will be running Windows Server with either server or client OSes for 2-6 simultaneous home users.

I'm used to AMD architecture, but I'm quite open to Intel if the costs seem to make sense, in terms of power to run it vs initial layout. Since the architecture is closely intertwined with the CPU and MOBO, I'm not sure how it's practical to separate the two, but I would say **let's focus on the motherboard**

**Requirements**

- At least 32 GB (preferably 64GB) of non-ECC RAM (because I'm not made of money)
- At least 8 cores/threads
- Gigbit LAN (preferably 2 ports) or , for NAS access
- no bigger than Full ATX

**Not Important**

- Lots of USB, SATA or PCI-E (whatever comes with is probably fine)
- Graphics interface (onboard or not doesn't matter to me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd essentially mirror my answer [here](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2124/531) and build something around a [X10SDV-6C+-TLN4F](http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon/D/X10SDV-6C_-TLN4F.cfm) Xeon-D based system. Newegg has it for a hair under the grand *including* an embedded CPU, and unlike some other models, it has a cooling solution. This dosen't include the ram but it'll take standard DDR4, and up to *64 gb* of non ECC stuff (or 128gb of Rdimm ram).

Lets talk about the nice things about this board.

Its an 8 core system, *designed* to run VMs, with a TDP of 45W.

Lan ports? 2x gig-e. 2x 10gig-e (should you need it).

Out of band management over IPMI. You can *install the OS over lan*.

One PCI x16, one M.2 slot, *6* sata 3 ports.

All in a *mini ITX form factor*.

You could go cheaper but I doubt you'd get all the same features. I've not actually gotten one, but I was seriously considering it at one point, when weighing my options for a home server.

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely take a look, as it meets the minimum requirements (2 or 3 users might be able to use simultaneously, but I'm thinking 4, 5, or 6 would be pushing it by quite a bit) - power use is one concern, for sure, but I'm not positive I wouldn't want a little more horsepower... I'll have to think on it - I might have to up those requirements :-P

Comment: first thing I see at the Supermicro page is that it says it's 6-core - I'll look for an 8-core version...?

Comment: I'm guessing you meant to recommend the _[X10SDV-8C-TLN4F](http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon/D/X10SDV-8C-TLN4F.cfm)_, which has the specs you listed, and is $1,200 on Newegg (looks cheaper elsewhere[?]), before RAM - not sure If I can go up, but I'm gonna keep looking into it

Comment: though, if you mean threads, I do believe they're HT, so 12 threads. Coulda sworn I had linked the 8 core version last tim.

Comment: in your linked post, your recommendation link includes the text "8C", but links to the "6C" version - I could imagine you dragged the link to this answer and then wrote the text for it based upon the URL? - idunno :-D - still really thinking about something with an integrated processor, though - quite possibly a good idea unless I'm willing to go with older processors (my other thought)

Comment: Haven't actually bought this yet, but seriously considering one of the slightly more expensive siblings of this board. Thanks for pointing it out